# Unable to find source of opencv function

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to find source code of `Laplacian(...)` in python.
But when I click on go to definition in vs code it give me just empty function as image below.
[image]

Please how can I find source code?

Comment: Chances are high that the Python version is just a wrapper over C++.

Comment: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/48cd2d190f28c002bac8a9a190d1fc16169eaece/modules/imgproc/src/deriv.cpp#L787

Answer (score 1, accepted):

opencv is implemented in c++. but algorithms can be accessed from python using  bindings

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d49/tutorial_py_bindings_basics.html

you cannot see python implementation because its not there. you can refer c++ explanations here
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gad78703e4c8fe703d479c1860d76429e6